# PHP/JS/AJAX/HTML: Dynamically creating a webpages

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my first time using AJAX i have been reading up on it, and it is also my first time doing this with js. I think i have confused myself along the way.

I am trying to dynamically create a new restaurant page, so every time a administrator clicks the onclick button a new webpage is created, with the content from the new restaurant page, which i have already created.

At the moment i have gotten as far as on pressing a button, a new webpage is created succesfully, however, i have no idea how to access the new webpage i also wanted to display a link to the newly created webpage as it is created, like for example using before. in js to show the dynamic feature before my o'clock button for example.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="makePage()">click</button>
<script src="makePage.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function makePage(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
}
var content = "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /> </head><body>new website<script>alert(\"test\")</script></body></html>";
xmlhttp.open("GET","makePage.php?content=" + content,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

**PHP**

```
<?php
$content = $_GET["content"];
$file = uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
echo $file;
?>
```

Any suggestions? guidance or related pages i can read up on. Anything will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your js do something like this instead of alert:

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var createA = document.createElement('a');
    var createAText = document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText); // or whatever name you need
    createA.setAttribute('href', xmlhttp.responseText);
    createA.appendChild(createAText);
    document.body.appendChild(createA); // or you can create some <div> or whatever and append it to that
}
```

This is plain javascript, but using jquery you can do it easier with [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) functions.

Comment: Great! by looking at it, it looks like what i am looking for. Thank you for taking out your time. I will try it a little later, as well as look at the links you provided